# Google Maps GMSMaker iconView - iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Error:

> value of type GMSmarker has no member iconView

How can I  use iconView?

```
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 13.7990609, longitude: 100.5494513)
        marker.title = "Coffee Factory"
        marker.snippet = "Chatuchak"
        marker.iconView = imageView
        marker.map = mapView
```

[image: Value of type GMSmarker has no member iconView]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you're using the latest Google Maps SDK v2.3.0 and above.

Try this:

```
    marker.icon = UIImage(named: "<Your Image>")
```

EDIT:

Or you can set `UIImageView` to `iconView`

```
    marker.iconView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "<Your Image>"))
```

Output:

[image: Screen shot]

Hope it helps.

Comment: i need to set icon is UIImageView not UIImage

Comment: @teezanateep You can do both ways, check my edited answer. Also, make sure you're using the latest Google Maps SDK v2.3.0 and above.

Comment: @teezanateep Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: restaurant.latitude, longitude: restaurant.longitude)
   marker.title = restaurant.name
 marker.icon = xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it's what i'm done with this. Hope it will also work for you.

**Swift 3.0**

```
let marker = GMSMarker()

let markerImage = UIImage(named: "mapMarker")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

let markerView = UIImageView(image: markerImage)

marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 33.5067, longitude: 51.2045)

marker.iconView = markerView
marker.map = mapView
```